# Getting the name of all DataMembers in a DataContract

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I am using WCF service

I have a Data Contract:

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(CustomBranches))]
public class CustomBranches
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string branch_name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string address_line_1 { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string city_name { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible that i can find the name of all the DataMembers in this class **CustomBranches**

Like "ID" , "branch name" etc

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seeing as it's a data-contract you should most likely have all these properties available, but if not the following should list all properties of your type:

```
Type T =(typeof(T));
var properties = T.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.Instance);
```

replace T with the type, and you're good to go. Depending on your needs you  might want different [BindingFlags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx).

Comment: Type typ = (typeof(T));
T cannot be both the type and the Type variable name. Also T should be reserved for generic types in generics. Thanks for the tip anyway.

Answer (score 16):

What you need to do:

- You don't need to add `[KnownType(typeof(CustomBranches))]` in your `CustomBranches` class. A class always knows about itself.
- You need to filter the properties to only get those with the `[DataMember]` attribute (nillls' code returned all of them)
- The data member properties can also be non-public (it works if the serialization is running in full trust)
- Data members can also be fields (not only properties), so you need to account for them as well.

This is an example of a code which does all of them.

```
public class StackOverflow_8152252
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        BindingFlags instancePublicAndNot = BindingFlags.Instance |
            BindingFlags.Public |
            BindingFlags.NonPublic;
        var memberNames = typeof(CustomBranches)
            .GetProperties(instancePublicAndNot)
            .OfType<MemberInfo>()
            .Union(typeof(CustomBranches).GetFields(instancePublicAndNot))
            .Where(x => Attribute.IsDefined(x, typeof(DataMemberAttribute)))
            .Select(x => x.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("All data member names");
        foreach (var memberName in memberNames)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("  {0}", memberName);
        }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class CustomBranches
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string branch_name { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string address_line_1 { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string city_name { get; set; }

        public int NonDataMember { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string FieldDataMember;

        [DataMember]
        internal string NonPublicMember { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that a type's ancestors, if any, each have their own `DataContract` attribute.  So for filtering properties and fields, you may want to include the `DeclaredOnly` binding flag.  In that case, also pass `inherit: false` to `IsDefined`.

Answer (score 3):

I have modified Carlos' answer slightly to ignore data members decorated with a `[NonSerialized]` attribute:

```
public class StackOverflow_8152252
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        BindingFlags instancePublicAndNot = BindingFlags.Instance |
            BindingFlags.Public |
            BindingFlags.NonPublic;
        var memberNames = typeof(CustomBranches)
            .GetProperties(instancePublicAndNot)
            .OfType<MemberInfo>()
            .Union(typeof(CustomBranches).GetFields(instancePublicAndNot))
            .Where(x => Attribute.IsDefined(x, typeof(DataMemberAttribute))
                     && !Attribute.IsDefined(x, typeof(NonSerializedAttribute)))
            .Select(x => x.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("All data member names");
        foreach (var memberName in memberNames)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("  {0}", memberName);
        }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class CustomBranches
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        [NonSerialized]
        public string NonSerializedDataMember { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had several properties with custom data member names defined like this:

**[DataMember(Name = "alternate_name")]**

I've modified mbonness' answer to return the custom names when present, or the default property names otherwise.

```
public class StackOverflow_8152253
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        BindingFlags instancePublicAndNot = BindingFlags.Instance |
            BindingFlags.Public |
            BindingFlags.NonPublic;
        var memberNames = typeof(CustomBranches)
            .GetProperties(instancePublicAndNot)
            .OfType<MemberInfo>()
            .Union(typeof(CustomBranches).GetFields(instancePublicAndNot))
            .Where(x => Attribute.IsDefined(x, typeof(DataMemberAttribute))
                     && !Attribute.IsDefined(x, typeof(NonSerializedAttribute)))
            .Select(x => x.CustomAttributes.FirstOrDefault(a => a.AttributeType == typeof(DataMemberAttribute))?.NamedArguments.FirstOrDefault(n => n.MemberName == "Name").TypedValue.Value ?? x.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("All data member names");
        foreach (var memberName in memberNames)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("  {0}", memberName);
        }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class CustomBranches
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "alternate_name")]
        public string PropertyWithAlternateName { get; set; }
    }
}
```